# Problem with connectionstring and entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a database (sql 2008 mdf file), a class library project with an edmx file, created with the wizard. So the connection string is also made by the wizard. 
This project is on a teamfoundation server.

I can use all the wizard made objects when coding.

But when i run the program and I try to make an entityContainerName, the program crashes and gives this error:

> The specified named connection is
>   either not found in the configuration,
>   not intended to be used with the
>   EntityClient provider, or not valid.

on this line:
 public TestEntities() : base("name=TestEntities", "TestEntities")

How can I solve this problem or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to copy the connection string from the class library's config file into the config file of the application that is actually running.

Answer (score 1):

First: delete your model, second: delete all the connectionstrings in your app.config.

Then recreate the model. This should set everything back to default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you want to use EntityFramework in a Class Library that means that your application should not be aware of the DB configurations. This is my point of view. How i solved this issue.
We remove all connection string from all App.Config files.
And we use instantiate our context with the connection already created.

```
public class ExpertDataBase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }

    public ExpertDataBase()
        : base(ConnectionFactory.GetCESqlConnection(),true)
    {

    }
}

public static class ConnectionFactory
{
   public static DbConnection GetCESqlConnection()
   {
       DbConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection()
           {
               ConnectionString = @"Data   Source= ",
           };
       return connection;
   }
}
```

This is my implementation and it works without me entering any connection string in any xml. This connectionFactory can be refactored so i can be injected somehow and use UnityContainer to resolve the connection type. 
Hope this helps